# AppVeyor ignores explicit assemly name for Unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, appveyor

I'm trying to setup AppVeyor for my project ([here](https://github.com/Sergio0694/NeuralNetwork.NET)) and I can't seem to find a way to only have it run tests from the .NET Core Unit test project.

This is the link for the AppVeyor project: [ci.appveyor.com/project/Sergio0694/neuralnetwork-net](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Sergio0694/neuralnetwork-net)

I also have a .NET Framework Unit test project that executes some GPU-based tests, so they just fail when run with AppVeyor as they're missing both a CUDA GPU and the required cuDNN files.

This is my configuration:

```
version: 1.0.{build}
image: Visual Studio 2017
before_build:
- cmd: dotnet restore
build:
  verbosity: minimal
test:
  assemblies:
    only:
    - NeuralNetwork.NET.Unit.dll
  categories:
    except:
    - NetworkTest
```

> That `NetworkTest` category that's skipped is just a group of tests that are very CPU intensive and require some time to run, so I'm just skipping them now to make the builds finish sooner.

The project builds fine, but AppVeyor keeps running the tests in the other NeuralNetwork.NET.Cuda.Unit.dll assembly as well, which fail as expected and cause the whole build to be marked as failing.

So my questions are:

- Am I doing something wrong here? Why isn't the assembly constraint respected?
- Is there another way to have AppVeyor only run the tests from NeuralNetwork.NET.Unit.dll?

**EDIT:** I've tried to set the "all assemblies excluding" option and all of these combinations to specify the .NET Framework Unit test project to skip:

- NeuralNetwork.NET.Cuda.Unit.dll
- **\*.NeuralNetwork.NET.Cuda.Unit.dll
- **\NeuralNetwork.NET.Cuda.Unit.dll

The tests keep being executed (failing as expected), am I missing something here?

**EDIT #2:** This is the workaround I'm using for now, I've manually excluded all the test categories in the .NET Framework project and so far this seems to be working (even if it's not so clean to see):

```
version: 1.0.{build}
image: Visual Studio 2017
configuration: Release
before_build:
- cmd: dotnet restore
build:
  verbosity: minimal
test:
  categories:
    except:
    - CuDnnInceptionLayerTest
    - CuDnnLayersTest
    - GpuExtensionsTest
    - SerializationTest
```

Comment: Try to use your own `test_script`, like https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/appveyor.yml Then you get all the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core tests detection works differently than detection of classic .NET Framework tests. When searching .NET Core tests, AppVeyor look for `.csproj` files with certain properties, not for assemblies. Assembly filter does not work for .NET Core tests (Categories filter works though).

Sorry for confusion. Created [this issue](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/2022) to implement behavior similar to assembly name filtering, but based on `.csproj` file names for .NET Core tests auto-detection.

For now workaround is to do a "black list", e.g. list all .NET Framework assemblies you do not want to run under `assemblies/except`. You can use wildcard syntax to make it more compact as described [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/running-tests/#selecting-assemblies-andor-categories-to-test).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! I've tried to set the mode as "all except *" (I've updated my question with more info), but those tests are still executed, I'm not sure why 

Comment: Looking into next post you made it work I believe. If not, share your build config in YAML format (`Export YAML` menu)

Comment: Unfortunately no, for now (as a workaround) I've only managed to exclude those Cuda tests by manually adding the exclusion for all the test categories in that project. It works, but it'd be much better to just exclude the whole test assembly (so that if I add more test categories to it in the future I won't have to also add the exclusion for those categories too).

Comment: Share you build config in YAML format (Export YAML menu). You can send it to team at appveyor dot com.

Comment: Sure thing, I've posted the additional YAML config with the workaround in the question and I'll also send a support email to that address, thanks!